# Powershell can't access Object attributes field and values

Tags: powershell, cmd, powershell-4.0

I'm working on to get the cmd command output in Powershell. The cmd command I ran as follows.

```
$obj = cmd.exe /c 'twiddle -s localhost -u xyz -p abc get "service=tempservice" stats'
```

If I print the object it prints the value as

```
Stats=[Ljava.lang.String;@c43b53
```

I want to access the value of this string object in PowerShell so that I can have all the fields and values of this $obj. I'm looking to get the value of one attribute and field named "count=1020132" inside the stats.

My Get-Member doesn't have any property or method which can help me in that.

I tried doing $obj."property" but didn't help.

Comment: I edited the question. Can you take a look at the command especially quotation marks. I tried & but no luck

Comment: Invoking any external program from PowerShell only ever returns _strings_ (whose only property is their `.Length`). You'll have to do _string parsing_ to extract information of interest. Update your question to describe what information you need to extract from the string returned - assuming that the information of interest is even present.

Comment: I'm looking for the count=100201 attribute inside the stats.

Comment: Please add clarifications directly to your question - don't use comments. It looks like you're getting a Java object's default string representation, which doesn't contain the actual property values, so you'll have to make `twiddle` output a suitable _serialized representation_ of the object's contents in text form, such as in JSON form. As an aside: There is no need to involve `cmd.exe` in calling `twiddle` - just call it directly from PowerShell.

Comment: so how can I make twiddle output a suitable serialized representation? I just need the count value. It can be in any format like json or xml

Comment: I don't know what `twiddle` is, but I encourage you to read its documentation and see if you can get a usable output format. If it should be possible but you struggle with the implementation, you can ask specific questions.

Comment: I couldn't find anything related to that and that is the reason I asked in stackoverflow if someone had faced similar issue gathering MBean data. twiddle is just the command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to do it with regex using named capture groups.
Please be so kind and adapt the regular expression to your needs, the used one is only an example.

```
    $str ='Stata=[Ljava.lang.String;@c43b53';
    [regex]$rx = "(?<trailer>\S+)\=\[(?<first>\S+)\.(?<second>\S+)\.(?<third>\S+);(?<leader>\S+)";

    $m = $rx.Match($str);
    $m;
    $m.Groups["trailer"].Value;
    $m.Groups["first"].Value;
    $m.Groups["second"].Value;
    $m.Groups["third"].Value;
    $m.Groups["leader"].Value;
```

Comment: Write-Output $m
Write-Output ---
Write-Output $m.Groups["count"].Value

Comment: Groups   : {$obj, $obj}
Success  : True
Captures : {$obj}
Index    : 0
Length   : 4
Value    : $obj

---
$obj

Comment: it doesn't print the value yet

Comment: I can't understand your problems. Yes, you can use Write-Output or Write-Host. But the above code is still working on my system and produces output to screen.

Comment: I added a semikolon in each line to prevent from other line endings (LF or CRLF)